# Recommendation for software and hardware setup for local transfer/stream of large files upto 100gb fastest without internet just locally using wifi

Tags: streaming, wifi, data-transfer

Need:-
(Using windows os on PC)

1. I had a daily need to tranfer over 60GB of single files between Android and PC and vice versa via wifi without using any internet
2. Also i had a need to stream Large upto 60GB media files like MKV and WAV files to be played from pc/external usb harddrive to smartphone. Thus Local media server fast

USB transfer is not possible as i have old pc with worn out usb sockets and also usb 1.0 max. Also USB transfer of file over 4gb always  breaks.

Please suggest me external wifi hardware and softwares setup that can let me transfer and also stream such large files as fastest as possible locally without internet just using wifi.

I can invest in high end router once for high speed wifi but i am confused how to achive this without using actual intenet.

Please someone suggest me setup